# Determining billing based on which API Key was used?

Tags: twilio

My organization is using the Twilio SDK in C# to sms and mms messages with a single long code. We have several teams in several different departments using it for various purposes and are looking to track how much of the bill belongs to each team. Each team has an API Key that they are using to authenticate their calls to send a message: `TwilioClient.Init(apiKey,apiSecret,accountSid);`

Is there anyway to see in the sms logs a breakdown of which API Key was used to send messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not. You can however use sub-accounts which are logical containers of resources, and then the usage API to determine usage by subaccount.

Comment: Can subaccounts use the phone number of the master account?

Comment: No, they cannot. It is a container and has its own numbers.